# Duplicate IAM Permissions in Google Cloud Platform for another user

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a user with permissions across many projects (see image below).

I have a new user who just joined the company. I want to give him the exact same permissions. How can I do this? I don't want to do it manually because that will take me ages and the Google Cloud Documentation is useless! I  cant find much on using `gcloud` command line to do this with examples.

There must be a easy way to duplicate permission?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to grant a role to a member for more than one project:

- Open the IAM & Admin Projects page in the GCP Console.
- Select all the projects for which you want to grant permissions.
- Click the Show Info Panel, followed by the Permissions tab.
- Enter an email address in the Add members field, and select the desired role from the drop-down menu.
- Click the Add button. The member will be granted the selected role in each of the selected projects.

Granting access rights to project is an action fraught with security risks, so bulk gcloud commands or simple copying of roles are understandably not supported.

You can find more detail on the "Granting, Changing, and Revoking Access to Resources" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant_access).

Comment: Regarding the 4th Bullet point - The only issue I get with this is that the role I want (Cloud SQL Admin) is not there. I cant find it and it is not a custom role

Comment: Cloud SQL Admin is the second role from the top, when you add new members in the Console.

Comment: For me its not :S. I cant even find it.

Comment: Which page are you looking at, when following the steps in the answer above? Have you clicked the "add" button?

Comment: 'Granting access rights to project is an action fraught with security risks, so bulk gcloud commands or simple copying of roles are understandably not supported' - please allow me to disagree with the end result GCP has achieved following that mantra. Having to manually cherry pick dozens of permissions is fraught with at least an equal amount of risk and often leads to re-use of service accounts due to the sheer amount of error-prone manual work that needs to be done.